# Use custom sort key properly with list of file strings

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a function that I found that sorts a list of files strings by number. I found this on the internet and it works great. But, I want to simply it so it's not all done on one line, and it's more readable for other people. But, I'm having a difficult time doing this because I don't understand the sorted function key, and lambda's very well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Input**

```
input_list = ['file_stuff_1','file_stuff_23','file_stuff_4','file_stuff_6']
```

**Code**

```
output = sorted(input_list, key=lambda x: int("".join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()])))
```

**Output**

```
['file_stuff_1','file_stuff_4','file_stuff_6','file_stuff_23']
```

---

**Attempt**

This was my first attempt at it. But I'm not sure how to fix digits so it works as a key.

```
def sort_list(input_list):

    for item in input_list:
        if (item.isdigit()):
            digits = int(''.join(item))
            output = sorted(input_list,digits)

    return output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_nums_from_filename(file_name):
    digits = [char for char in file_name if char.isdigit()]
    return int(''.join(digits))

input_list = ['file_stuff_1','file_stuff_23','file_stuff_4','file_stuff_6']

sorted(input_list, key=get_nums_from_filename)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions

the "key" param in sorted() specifies a function that should be applied to each item to get a resulting value, then sorting of the original values is done based on the corresponding resulting values.

Comment: Thanks! That works, do you know why this actually works? The function returns a string of numbers. I don't really understand how sort can use that to figure out what to sort.

Comment: ''.join(digits) makes a string of numbers.

The int() part changes that from a string to an integer, so the function returns an integer.

sorted() uses the integer to sort